# how to catch CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException when using openCsv

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, opencsv

I use OpenCSV for CSV files reading and writing. I am stuck at handling the exception when a required column is missing in the csv file. Below is the code :

```
CsvToBean<T> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(new FileReader(file))
          .withType(targetClazz)
          .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.BOTH)
          .withThrowExceptions(false)
          .build();

      List<T> correctlyParsed = beans.parse();
      List<String[]> linesWithErrors = buildListOfLinesWithErrors(beans.getCapturedExceptions());
```

This works fine till I receive the all the headers as defined in the Java object. But, if any one is missing, I get the below error:

```
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Header is missing required fields [X]. The list of headers encountered is [A, B, C, D].
```

This error is caused from line

```
List<T> correctlyParsed = beans.parse();
```

The only way I could handle this error is by adding a catch block for RuntimeException. But catching RuntimeException doesn't seem to be good coding.
Please suggest if there is a way around.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you going to do if and when you catch it?

Comment: As per requirement, need to upload the csv to s3 bucket and send an email

Comment: That's not what I meant

Comment: Well, if header is not present in the csv to process, I have to store the csv in s3. As mentioned, if header is not present a runtime exception is thrown from bean.parse(), and that's the problem.

Comment: *Well, if header is not present in the csv to process, I have to store the csv in s3* Surely you mean if the header IS present?

Comment: No, even if it's not present, have to store in s3 , in error folder.

Comment: OK. I wouldn't get too hung up about it being a `RuntimeException`. That might be the case only to save you the hassle of *having* to catch it. So, catch it, and then just upload it as a file to the error folder

Comment: I was hoping to find a cleaner solution, because catching a RuntimeException doesn't seem to be good coding practice.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it if you have to.